# Разбор и генерация URL для basic приложения YII2

Tags: framework, yii2, php, фреймворк

Доброго всем времени суток.
Возможно ли средствами **.htaccess** или **php** превращать адрес
`http://www.example.com/basic/web/index.php` в
`http://www.example.com/index.php`.
Ведь на живом хостинге никто не даст редактировать файл `httpd.conf`, а ссылка "Разбор и генерация URL" и многие другие на `github.com` дают 404 ошибку. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно установить в правильную директорию. ../basic/web - корневая для сайта должна быть web.

У обычных хостингов, как правило, все скрипты в одной корневой директории. Нужно содержимое web перенести на директорию ниже, внутри index.php изменить пути для корректной работы,  проверить, не сломались ли права на запись assets. Содержимое basic нужно перенести на директорию ниже, проверить права на запись runtime, чтобы не сломались.

Вроде все, пишите, что получилось.

Comment: Да, ваш вариант приведён по аналогии с генерацией проектов на YII версии 1х, но для 2х в документации сказано "Информация: Устанавливая basic/web корневой директорией веб сервера вы защищаете от нежелательного доступа код и данные, находящиеся на одном уровне с basic/web. Это делает приложение более защищенным." Т.е. я так понял что мне из корня нужно достучаться до web/index.php при том, что явно его указывать не нужно.

Comment: Я полагаю, вы находитесь в начале пути. У типичного хостинга одна директория html_public, с которой, как мне, очень трудно работать с архитектурой, о которой вы говорите. Когда вы будете работать с такими хостингами, как DititalOcean или настоящими серверами (в больших компаниях так оно и происходит), под вашим управлением будет доступна любая реализация архитектуры приложения. А сейчас вам нужно разобраться с тем, как менять её в принципе, чтобы завести приложение.

П.С. Уверен также, что вы работаете еще и под виндой. =)

Comment: Да, я работаю из вод W8.1 и у меня стоит OpenServer. Ваш вариант я понял, т.е. вы советуете мне просто из папки web перенести проект на уровень вверх? Благодарю за ответ. Надеюсь, на реальном сервере данная проблема остро не встанет.

Comment: До тех пор пока вы не программируете на linux машине, у вас всегда будет проблема одной директории.